# video with javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, video-player

So for the past few days I've been messing around with javascript and html. On html 5 video tags. I wanna create a solid video-player without jquery. I have had a look at different tutorials regards custom controls like volume, play and pause and fullscreen. I wanna dive in a little more but not having much look on finding a good source, regarding some more advance controls. Things like hovering on the timeline and getting an image of what is shown at the time. Pretty much like the way youtube and other video players work. Adding more tuff stuff like time information, scrub bar, key moments, micro-scrubbing and subtitles.

Can anyone point me in a direction where I could find anything like what i've listed?

Thank you :D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question does seems to be off-topic, please consider the guidelines [*"What topics can I ask about here?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML video tag can provide all you need fro embedding media inside your page

a good guide is provide by [this Mozilla MDN Using HTML5 audio and video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

from the simple tag

> ```
>  <video src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" controls>
>      Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
>  </video>
> ```

to the controlling media playback for audio an video

> ```
> <audio id="demo" src="audio.mp3"></audio>
> <div>
>    <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').play()">Play the Audio</button>
>    <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').pause()">Pause the Audio</button>
>    <button  onclick="document.getElementById('demo').volume+=0.1">Increase Volume</button>
>     <button> onclick="document.getElementById('demo').volume-=0.1">Decrease  Volume</button>
>   </div>
> ```